# Adobe Air, need to lauch windows virtual keyboard osk.exe

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air

From an Adobe Air application, I need a function to launch the Windows Virtual Keyboard (c:\windows\system32\osk.exe).

I tried the Native Process, but it didn't work when telling it to execute `cmd.exe /C osk.exe`.

How should I launch the keyboard application from an Adobe Air application?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider implementing your own AS3 keyboard within your app.
Something like this maybe...

http://activeden.net/item/on-screen-virtual-keyboard-as-30/55005